# Auto resize UIView based on multi line UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

**Problem:**
I have a custom view with a multi-line UILabel (se picture below).

[image]

This custom view is then added to a screen in my storyboard (se picture below).

[image]

This works great. The problem is that the multi-line label will change dynamically a few times under execution, and then the blue UIView box won't fit. It's also a problem with smaller/bigger screen size.

**Question:** So how do I get the UIView to automatically resize in height according to the height of the UILabel? Is it possible to do through Interface Builder and Autolayout? (not nececery, but most of my other settings are done through IB)

Let me know if there is more details needed.

Comment: why not use a `UIStackView` ? Do you need to support iOS 8 too?

Comment: @dirtydanee Hi, no need to support iOS 8. How would I go about solving this with UIStackView?

Comment: I am looking at it currently, will let you know soon.

Comment: Simply put it in table view cell and put tableview.height = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 3):

As long as you make sure that **labels** in your **custom view** are pinned to all **sides** (Title Label pinned to: Leading, Top, Trailing of the superview and Bottom to Content Label; Content Label pinned to: Leading, Bottom, Trailing of the **superview** and Top to Title Label) you will have your **superview** change it's height according to the content.

Also, note that your **superview** won't need a height **constraint**, just pinning it to the Leading, Bottom and Trailing sides should be sufficient.

I had almost identical view in one of my apps. What I would do to make sure the height changes according to update is this:

```
customView.setNeedsLayout()
customView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

You can also wrap this code in UIView.animate(withDuration: ...) block

Cheers!

Comment: Note, the custom view must have a width constraint for this to work.